# How can I define A and B depending from each other typed class using refined library?

Tags: scala, refined

**Problem:**

I have a case class Passenger, that starts from point A and goes to point B.

A valid passenger means that point A doesn't equal to point B.

```
Passenger(
  a: Int,
  b: Int
)
```

**Question:**

How can I design Passenger class using [refind](https://index.scala-lang.org/fthomas/refined/refined/0.9.2?target=_2.12) library to reach the goal?

I think Passenger should take two or one refined type parameters, something like:

```
    Passenger[A, B Refined NotEqual[A]](...)
```

**Example:**

I expect that the following code doesn't compile:

```
Passenger(42, 42)
```

And this compiles correctly:

```
Passenger(1, 42)
```

Comment: Here is the link how it works in Haskell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53961764/can-i-define-parametric-data-type-where-parameters-are-not-equals-between-in-has

Comment: `a` and `b` are passed parameters which are only known at run-time, therefore I don't think a compile-time check is going to be possible.