# Can I define parametric data type where parameters are not equals between in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems, refinement-type, liquid-haskell

**Problem:**

Let's imagine we have a Passenger with start and end points represented by:

```
data Passenger a = Passenger { start :: a
                               , end :: a
                             }
```

**Question:**

How can I apply a class constraints to Passenger, where the start point shouldn't be equal to the end point?

**P.S.:**
I have asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359774/how-can-i-define-a-and-b-depending-from-each-other-typed-class-using-refind-libr) in the Scala community, but I didn't receive any answer. Considering that [refined library for scala](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) is inspired by [refined for Haskell](https://github.com/nikita-volkov/refined), also hearing about liquid-Haskell, I wonder how can resolve it using Haskell?

Comment: You cannot do this via types alone in standard Haskell – that would require dependent types. Use a [smart constructor](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors) instead, or use liquid Haskell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just saw this. You can do so by specifying a refinement on the `end` field, e.g.:

```hs
{-@ data Passenger a = Passenger 
      { start :: a
      , end   :: {v:a | v /= start} 
      } 
  @-}

data Passenger a = Passenger 
  { start :: a
  , end   :: a
  }                        

ok :: Passenger String 
ok = Passenger "Alice" "Jones"

bad :: Passenger String
bad = Passenger "Bora" "Bora"
```

You can play with this online here:

http://goto.ucsd.edu:8090/index.html#?demo=permalink%2F1551137259_16583.hs